# 塩気/塩っ気 (shiokke) = sass?

Tags: meaning, words, expressions, slang

In Shinya Shokudou (Midnight Diner) S3EP06, and old mom meets with this old guy, and they're talking at a diner in front of the old mom's daughter (who's casual friends with the old guy). The old mom's being super gregarious and flirty, and is like "I booked a hotel with a large bed, but it's so lonely here". Then the old guy's like "俺はよ、塩っ気と色っ気には弱えんだよ".

[image: english subs for the line]

I understand everything about the sentence, except the 塩気｛しおけ｝ part. I know the word means "salty" normally, but the subs go out of their way to say that, in the context, it means "sass". However, when looking it up, I'm not sure I can find anything of the sort. Can anyone corroborate this? At the very least, in America, "salty" often implies one is angry/miffed in modern contexts (e.g. a salty loser), or very seasoned/experienced in older contexts (e.g. a salty seadog).

Comment: It looks to me like it's just a different culture using a different metaphor, and translators attempting to clear that up.

Comment: Does 塩気 refer to a property of women? It looks like to me that he's saying he likes salty foods.

Comment: Just guessing here, but would it be similar to the english expression of saying "someone has a touch of spice", or "someone has a spicy personality", meaning that person is lively, has high spirits, or is high energy?

Answer (score 1):

If the word [塩対応](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A1%A9%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C) (recent slang) has clearly been mentioned in the context, someone might playfully refer to it as 塩っ気. Otherwise, 塩気 on its own does not have any metaphorical meaning, so he is probably just saying he likes salty foods. Of course, he brought it up to rhyme with 色っ気.